# how to find a usr in a many to many field DRF

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a model in Django with many to many field
I want to find out if the user is in the many-to-many field
is there any way to check other than iterating all objects and for each object checking if the user is in its many-to-many fields? I have something like this in mind:

```
user = request.user
all  = myObject.objects.all()
filtered = filter(lambda Object: user in Object.field.all(), all)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simplify the logic like this (not played with `Queryset`)

```
user = "W"

a=[
    {'key1':'value1',
    'key2':'value2',
    'key3':'value3',
    'key4':['A','B','C']},
]

for i in a:
    if user_name in  i['key4']:
        print('Yes! User exist')
    else:
        print('No! User Does not exist')
```

#### NOTE - Here `'key4':['A','B','C']` is considered a many-to-many field

### Output

```
Yes! User exist
------ OR ------
No! User Does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use in keyword

```
user = request.user
all  = myObject.objects.all()
has_user_available = user in all
```